# D3 line style when using step-before or step-after interpolation

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js, interpolation

I have a line chart using step-before interpolation (though the same question applies if step-after is used). I want the vertical line segments to be colored lighter than the horizontal line segments. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the chart?

Comment: Here's a simple example using Rickshaw. I'd like the vertical segments to be a lighter shade of blue. http://jsfiddle.net/XUsFc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single path must be in a single colour. You'd have to break the chart up into individual paths, one for each vertical and horizontal piece in order to colour them individually.